# Files and folders automatically deleted. How to recover them?

Tags: 14.04, data-recovery, testdisk

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.5. Everything was ok till yesterday. Today when I opened my laptop, some folder and files inside them were missing. I am quite sure I didn't deleted them. I deleted only one folder `EAP4.0` . But all my important files were gone,from a specific folder. Also, it is notable that not all files and folders inside that folder are deleted.

I tried to recover files from `testdisk` after following links: [How to recover deleted files in ubuntu using live usb?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/676242/how-to-recover-deleted-files-in-ubuntu-using-live-usb-based-on-filetype) and [Data Recovery From Accidentally Deleted Files or Crashed Drives in Ubuntu](https://www.howtoforge.com/data_recovery_from_accidently_deleted_files_or_crashed_drives_in_ubuntu).

I got some data, but there were hundereds of .txt and .png files. None were of my use. I had lost some node and java projects which I wanted to recover. But it seems quite difficult to retrieve data from what is returned by `TestDisk` to me. There are 140 folders and hundreds of files inside them with random names.

I have googled a lot about this but only solution I got was to use `TestDisk` and `photorec`. But none seems to give proper folders. Is there any way I can recover my projects?

Also I am interested to know, How my files and folders were automatically deleted. I repeat, I am quite sure I did not deleted any of them. I am amused how the hell this could happen.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just restore them from your backup ..

Comment: I had no backup. :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unnoticingly I deleted a directory. Is there a way to recover it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/603549/unnoticingly-i-deleted-a-directory-is-there-a-way-to-recover-it)

Comment: This is a grandfather question from 2016. Leave open.