# Recover Data ext4

Tags: data-recovery

I need help and I hope someone can help me.

I lost my data, and on those data I had an application that I did work for about a year.
The way I've lost data is weird, and to help me is important to explain how i lost my data.
I tried to delete something form my root but made mistake and I deleted everything from root,
than I installed ubuntu-mate again on that same partition,
when I loged in to the system, the other parition is empty even though its space of data is still there,
and what is even more weird I have another disk just for keeping my data, no system on it is installed, it has
three partitions and the partition where I have my files of my app that one is empty either, same there
partition is empty but usage of partition isn't, so is there a way that i can get data back, but I need em with folders cause with testdisk I can recover files but there are a lot of them and I can't find which file belong to my app, or should I just forget about it!

Thank You All.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unnoticingly I deleted a directory. Is there a way to recover it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/603549/unnoticingly-i-deleted-a-directory-is-there-a-way-to-recover-it)

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, you have just learnt a couple of painful lessons. We have, at one time or another, all been through this. Its no help to you at this stage.

1. Check that the partition with the missing data is being mounted. If you just reinstalled, your fstab may not be up to date.

I am really hoping here that in the panic to reinstall Ubuntu you didn't accidentally check the "Format []" box in the partition allocation dialog. That would be pretty disastrous, because it does reformat the disk. The only option at this point is to use a data recovery program on the disk. Format does not actually wipe the disk, it just write the index and super blocks. The data is still there, but you can't get to it because there are no file pointers to the blocks. A data recovery program MAY help.

You should also look at a backup policy. It is a truism that PC does not stand for Personal Computer. It really stands for perpetual catastrophe. If you have any critical data that you simply must not lose, always make sure you have a copy somewhere offline where the computer cannot ransack it. For me, thats a backup on AWS. If you have a cloud system, it can be on that. I used to use tapes, but that is just soooo old fashioned these days.

Comment: Reinstalling is even worse than just formatting.  At least with formatting, data can sometimes be recovered with data recovery tools like testdisk/photorec. But if you overwrite data, it's gone forever.

Comment: But don't understand why I lost data from other disk and at only one partition , not the disk that I have the OS